# how to use php path in css?

Tags: php, css

I am trying to give path to an image through a php variable in css like this:

```
<?php $path= "www.ghhelpline.com/hello/images/" ?>

    <style>
    .hello { 
        background-image: url("<?php echo $path;?>new.png");
    }
    </style>
```

Is it possible or not?

if not tell me other way to do this.

Comment: yes this way of adding is possible

Comment: It is possible but you forgot a semicolon after $path declaration

Comment: That works... add http to the path.

Comment: Is a semicolon required after $path declaration?

Comment: @Vasilis Yes and as far as I know sctyle is not a valid html tag :)

Comment: correct ur spelling mistake *style

Comment: @user1887832 - try adding `http://` before link starts.. and if not working then check your `html` code once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php 
    $path= "http://www.ghhelpline.com/hello/images/"; //add http before link starts..
?>
<style>    
    .hello {
         background-image: url('<?php echo $path;?>new.png');
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. (Woohoo!)

To make this possible, your server needs to interprete the file, so either modify the settings, that the server also looks into .css-files, or rename it to .php.

Also, don't forget the http://, otherwise the path would be interpreted as relative path.

Comment: it's wrapped in a style tag so it's not in a css file. No need to interpret.

Comment: @TimJoyce: Ooops, didn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of file. If you are using this code in a .php file, you can do this, but if you are using it in a .css file, you cannot.

This is because the PHP interpreter does not parse this type of files.

Answer (score -1):

add protocol...`http://`

```
<?php $path= "http://www.ghhelpline.com/hello/images/" ?>
```